# How to manange multiple roles and sub-paths in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

What follows is a piece of my current Spring Security configuration:

```
...
<intercept-url pattern="/foo/bar/**" access="hasRole('adminViewer')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/foo/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />
....
```

which basically lets an admin to visit any part of the site under `foo/`, and an adminViewer to visit **only** the area under `foo/bar/`.

It works fine so far, except for those users whose roles are both `admin` and `adminViewer`. In such case, an `adminViewer` is allowed to visit also the admin-only area, since it is an `admin` as well.

Is it possible to explicitly narrow the `adminViewer` permissions by forbidding the access to `/foo/`, with something like `forbid-access` or similar? Or is there any point I'm missing?

Comment: If user has both roles why do you want to restrict him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pavel Horal pointed out, your question doesn't really seem to make much sense. You should rather focus on creating clear roles where permissions and restrictions don't overlap.

That being said, you can change your expression like this to get your desired result:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/foo/**" access="hasRole('admin') and (!hasRole('adminViewer'))" />
```

Comment: Lukehey and @PavelHoral: you are both right, I'm just dealing with a messy (and untouchable for the moment) role management :). This solution works like a charm btw.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Good look cleaning it up :)